# equivalent of sox for video

Tags: linux, video, command-line, sox

I often use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) for editing audio. Is there an equivalent command line tool for editing video on Linux?

Comment: Because this is a "What program to use for task X?" questions I'm voting for a move to Super User.

Comment: "I often use sox for editing <del>video</del> <ins>audio</ins>"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ffmpeg, mencoder

Answer (score 1):

transcode is also worth looking into.  In the past I've found it to be better documented than ffmpeg,mencoder, but that might not be the case anymore.